# Abbreviating the definition of a tangent vector field?

Tags: functions, soft-question, notation, manifolds

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and let $F: A \to \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be continuous. Then $F$ is called a tangent vector field on $A$ if and only if $F(x) \in \{x\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ for all $x \in A$.

I am trying to reduce this definition to see if it is possible to somehow write the part "$F(x) \in \{ x \} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$" into the part "$F: A \to \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$". In other words, I am working to see if the definition can be written as the usual functional notation such as $f: x \mapsto x^{2} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, which is more appealing. But so far I have come up with no simpler methods.

Comment: I've seen $F: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ considered a vector field with the proviso that $F(x)$ is understood to be attached to $x$. Of course, the definition you write is a formalization of the informal slogan I give in this comment. Alternatively, you can define the tangent bundle and define a vector field as a section, but, I suspect that is further removed from your desire here.

Comment: Thank you for leaving a comment. At first glance it seems not difficult to "trim up" the definition. But, yes, not that easy as I thought.